# Simplifying $a\cdot\ln(x) + b\cdot\ln(y)$ as $\ln(x^a\cdot y^b)$

Tags: calculus, logarithms

I ran into a problem where i need to simplify the equation $p\cdot\ln(x) + (1-p)\ln(y)$.

Can I solve it by moving the multiplier on top of the log as such: $\ln(x)^p + \ln(y)^{(1-p)}$ and then using the logarithm property $\ln(x)+\ln(y)=\ln(x\cdot y)$, thus getting $\ln(x^p\cdot y^{(1-p)})$?

Comment: Please use MathJax. Here is a
[tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Comment: yes! you can do that.